# How to separate code: is my controller doing too much work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Here is a description of the code below:

1. router decides which controller method to call
2. controller gets model(s)
3. controller instantiates various views with model
4. controller instantiates layout, puts views into it
5. controller puts layout into app

Is controller doing too many things?  I guess the good way should be

1. router decides which controller method to call
2. controller gets model(s)
3. controller instantiates layout **with model**
4. controller puts layout into app.  *End of controller's work*
5. layout when initialized instantiates views with model

**Question**: Is the second approach better?
If so, how to do [3. and 5. of the good way]?

Code also in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xxf70w0/1/)

```
ContactMgr.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  appRoutes: {
    'contacts/:id'      : 'detail'
  }
});

ContactMgr.Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    detail: function (id) {
      var promise = App.request('contact:entities', id);
      $.when(promise).done( function (contacts) {
        var _model = contacts.get(id);

        var contactView = new MyContactView({ model: _model });
        var sideView = new MySideView({ model: _model });

        var view = new MyLayout();
        // MyLayout has mainRegion, sideRegion
        view.on('show', function (v) {
          v.getRegion('mainRegion').show(contactView);
          v.getRegion('sideRegion').show(sideView);
        });

        App.getRegion('contentRegion').show(view);
        // App has contentRegion, other regions

      });// when done, end
    }// detail, end
});
```

Comment: If this question gets closed, then you should probably ask on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). They are happy to talk about design issues.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363344/auto-init-and-show-view-within-a-region-on-a-marionette-layout) may be the answer.

And

```
ContactMgr.Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
  detail: function (id) {
    ...
    var _model = contacts.get(id);
    ...
    var view = new MyLayout({model: _model});
    App.getRegion('contentRegion').show(view);
  }
});

MyLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    ...
    regions: {
      mainRegion: '#...',
      sideRegion: '#...'
    },
    contactView: null,
    sideView: null,
    onShow: function () {
      this.getRegion('mainRegion').show(this.contactView);
      this.getRegion('sideRegion').show(this.sideView);
    },
    initialize: function (opt) {
      var _model = opt.model;
      this.contactView = new Marionette.ItemView({ model: _model });
      this.sideView    = new Marionette.ItemView({ model: _model });
    }

});
```